# Custom class constants

Tags: iphone, objective-c, constants

I made a custom class for my iPhone project. One of the properties of this class is an int and I want to be able to assign only a handful of values to that property. I like the way Cocoa does this with many of its own classes, like fox example, setting the cell selection style in a UITableView. I'd like to implement this in my own class.

I opened up the headers for some of Cocoa's classes and found out a bunch of typedef enums around there but being new to objective-c I couldn't quite figure out how to make them work for what I wanted to do (or even where to put these).

```
typedef enum {
    UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone,
    UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue,
    UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray
} UITableViewCellSelectionStyle;
```

So to recap... just like in Cocoa you'd do:

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
```

I'd like to do the same thing with my own classes:

```
myObject.myProperty = MyObjectMyPropertySomeValue;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare an enum to contain all the various options and name it:

```
typedef enum {
    MyObjectMyPropertySomeValue,
    MyObjectMyPropertySomeOtherValue,
    MyObjectMyPropertySomeThirdValue
} MyObjectMyPropertyValues;
```

Then, in your code,

```
@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) MyObjectMyPropertyValues myProperty;
```

I presume that you can figure out the rest - it's pretty standard.

<sub>Typed in bowser without being tested.</sub>